# How to flatten a list of maps?

Tags: elixir

I'm doing doing "map" over a collection and getting back a list of maps:

```
   res1 = Enum.map(my_collection, fn a ->
     %{a.id => get_some_data(a)}
   end) 

   # =>     [%{1 => 123}, %{2 => 456}]
```

How can I flatten the list of maps - res1 - so that I have this:

```
%{1 => 123, 2 => 456}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest thing here would be to construct a Keyword list during the map:

```
coll
|> Enum.map(fn a -> {a.id, get_some_data(a)} end)
|> Map.new
```

Or:

```
for a <- coll, id = a.id, data = get_some_data(a), into: %{} do
  {id, data}
end
```

The problem was that you were building a map on each iteration, rather than building a key/value pair, which is what Keyword lists/maps are made of.

Comment: `Enum.map_reduce` won't help?

Comment: It's just not necessary is all - you get the Keyword list for free by building a list of tuples, which Map.new can convert from, and using `for` the list construction is skipped entirely and the map is built directly, so that approach is more optimal.

Answer (score 4):

While both `Enum.map/2` and `Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1` perfectly do their job, there is also a possibility to achieve the same result with `Enum.reduce/3`:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ input = [%{id: 1, data: :foo}, %{id: 2, data: :bar}]
#⇒ [%{data: :foo, id: 1}, %{data: :bar, id: 2}]

iex|2 ▶ Enum.reduce(input, %{}, fn e, acc ->
...|2 ▷   Map.put(acc, e.id, e.data)
...|2 ▷ end)
#⇒ %{1 => :foo, 2 => :bar}
```